# Apache HttpClient 4 persistent connection per Proxy instead of per route

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x, persistent, apache-httpcomponents

My understanding, all implementations of ClientConnectionManager persist connections base on route. This results in basically no persistent connections if a proxy is involved. For example, the HttpClient needs to visit 1000 different domains via a HTTP proxy with an fix IP, it has to establish at least 1000 connection to the proxy instead of creating 1 persistent connection to the proxy and reuse that for the 1000 requests.

I'm simulating multiple users visiting thousands of domains (fake domains, all dns resolved to a couple of IPs, the resolving happen after the proxy, so nothing to do with HttpClient). The above behavior quickly use up all available ports in the localhost as I increase the # of users and domains, the Address Bind errors occur as result.

Is there a way to make the HttpClient to persist connection on proxy basis? ie. A HttpClient only maintain specified number of connections to a given proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After intensive research, it seems that Apache HttpClient doesn't support this behavior out-of-box. I have to modify the HttpClient/HttpCore source in order to have this feature, ie. maintain persistent connections based only on localAddress and First Proxy address.

The classes I modified are:

org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRounte.java and 
org.apache.http.conn.routing.BasicRouteDirector.java.

Basically I changed the hashCode and equal method in HttpRoute (which is used as a key to hashtable for persistent conn lookup), so the lookup doesn't consider target address if a proxy is involved.

Initial test results of above modification shows about 100 times improvement in terms of request throughput in my scenario. So far it works fine for me.

Kevin