# Apache HTTPClient 4.3.4 creates new connection for each HTTP request when using a proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, httpclient

My Web application needs to connect to a set of external URLs (HTTPs) through a proxy. I am using Apache httpclient 4.3.4 and during my test I see that the API creates a new HTTPs connection for each request while going through the proxy even though the target host for both the requests is the same. Is this intentional and by design?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425327/apache-httpclient-4-persistent-connection-per-proxy-instead-of-per-route) thread on stackoverflow which mentions a similar issue. However I would prefer not making any custom changes to the API as suggested on this thread. Also since this was around 4 years back I wanted to check if this is now possible in the latest version of the API and if I am missing something.

I am really looking to reuse the same HTTP/s connection established to the proxy unless there are justified reasons of not doing so. Also just FYI, for certain URLs which dont need the proxy, I can see that the same set of connections are reused. The application uses Spring and I am using the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I have found the same problem - every request forwarded by apache to the proxy requests a new client TCP connection. Following https://serverfault.com/questions/919733/difference-between-keepalive-in-apache2-conf-and-in-proxypass I have tried adding KeepAlive On in apache2.conf but this made no difference.